# keycloak - is it possible to let the users to choose a realm in login page

Tags: keycloak

we have to user groups in our company, staff and outsource, they are in the different realms. We want to let the user choose the realm on the login page. is it possible to do that? and will SSO work in this case? Currently, we use a javascript adapter for redirecting to the keycloak login page. If it is not possible can you suggest something in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add realm selector in FTL and redirect to selected realm

Comment: Can you elaborate on how it is possible to add realm selector in FTL ? I cannot find any documentation on this.

Comment: @Oliver Masseau FTL is the free marker template language, i.e., you need to edit the markup of keycloak but then you do need to know how to access the realm object in markup and how to modify the realm through it.

Answer (score 0):

Add realm selection to your APP UI and then redirected user to the Keycloak realm login page based on selected realm from the APP UI.